# how to call custom template in custom layout magento

Tags: magento

I have created custom layout named `innerpage.phtml` and location of file `/var/www/magento/app/design/frontend/sfreaks/default/template/page` . It working fine. Now I want to call custom template in this layout.

My custom template name is `flatfooter.phtml` and I have put it inside

`/var/www/magento/app/design/frontend/sfreaks/default/template/page` folder.

code which I am using for calling in layout `innerpage.phtml` is

```
<?php  echo $this->getChildHtml('flatfooter') ?>
```

I have define block in layout file `page.xml` at file location `/var/www/magento/app/design/frontend/sfreaks/default/layout`

with code `<block type="core/html_footer" name="flatfooter"  output="toHtml" template="page/flatfooter.phtml" />`

But its not working, anyone help please.

Comment: paicubes ,other default block is call perfectly ya not??just  like header call in header postion.

Comment: have you define <block type="core/html_footer" name="flatfooter" output="toHtml" template="page/flatfooter.phtml" /> under<default> tag ?

Comment: @AmitBera yes rest all are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this `<block type="page/html_footer" name="flatfooter" as="flatfooter" output="toHtml" template="page/flatfooter.phtml" />` hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

define under your default in page.xml

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
```

...
...
...

```
<block type="core/html_footer" name="flatfooter" output="toHtml" template="page/flatfooter.phtml" />
```

...
...
...

Comment: Yes I have put it under <default> tag